# Is it possible to track In-app messages on MobilePush SDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios, tracking

My team is implementing MobilePush, and we are facing some difficulties regarding analytics.

We checked the official SFMC MobilePush documents (both Android and iOS) , Android Javadocs, and iOS Appledoc. Push tracking and in-box tracking are covered; however, the documents neither explicitly mention that it is possible to track in-app messages nor provides the SDK code for the implementation--although it somewhat seems like it is possible to track in-app messages.

Does anyone have an experience implementing analytics codes regarding in-app message tracking? It would be a huge help! Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android SDK will track receipt and opens of InApp Messages.  The iOS SDK tracks receipt of InApp Messages, and I'm 99% sure it tracks opens too.  What I do not know is how/where you can see that reporting.  I would reach out to your account executive/manager and see if they can run a report for you.

Comment: Hey Bill, thanks a lot for your answer! May I ask what kind of receipt you meant in your answer? I tried to search for additional information but couldn't find any.

Comment: We collect "downloaded" (aka receipt), "completed" (aka viewed), and a few other analytics automatically.